# Returning data from a .txt file into an arraylist

Tags: java

Okay so I'm given a txt file with a couple objects that possesses the description, cost, and percent depreciated that the constructor asks for. In my `tostring()` method I just ask to return some values that I inputted. I left out all the methods that were used to calculate things like current value because they don't matter for the question I'm asking.

```
public class InventoryItem {

    private String description;
    private double cost, percentDepreciated;
    public static final double DEPRECIATION_MIN = 0.0,
            DEPRECIATION_MAX = 1.0;

    public InventoryItem(String descriptionIn, double costIn, double percentDepreciatedIn) {
        description = descriptionIn.trim();
        cost = costIn;
        percentDepreciated = percentDepreciatedIn;
    }
    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        String output;
        output = "Description: " + description;
        output += "\nCost: $" + df.format(cost);
        output += "\tPercent Depreciation: " + (percentDepreciated * 100 + "%");
        output += "\nCurrent Value: $" + df.format(currentValue());
        if (isEligibleToScrape()) {
            output += "\n*** Eligible to scape ***";
        }
        if (percentDepreciatedOutOfRange()) {
            output += "\n*** Percent Depreciated appears to be out of range ***";
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

So what I'm asking is now that I am given a txt file that has the information above for multiple objects, how would I return the information of each InventoryItem object and have it formatted like the above `toString()` method. I need to do this in the `toString()` method below in my Inventory class

```
public class Inventory {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<InventoryItem> inventoryList = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

    public Inventory(String nameIn, ArrayList<InventoryItem> inventoryListIn) {
        name = nameIn;
        inventoryList = inventoryListIn;
    }
    public String toString() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your .txt file contain the whole `toString()` method?

Comment: @BorisVerwoerd it contains the name of the inventory followed by the description, cost, and percent depreciated. Like this: 
    Used Car Inventory
    2012 Jeep
    32000
    .35
    1990 Toyota
    18000
    .95
    2013 Honda
    26000
    -.20
    2013 Ford
    22000
    1.20

Each value is returned on a new line it just wont let me do that in these comments

Comment: If the only purpose of `toString()` is to provide informative text, you can simply use `name + " " + inventoryList`.  That will invoke the toString() method of ArrayList, which in turn will include the string form of each of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that toString() method has a completely different purpose and it is a very bad idea to implement it this way. What you want is some sort of a 'text serializer' for your InventoryItem class.

As for the question itself (if you really really absolutely need to do it like this...) you can just create a StringBuilder and append output of each InventoryItem's toString() method to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you need to get data from a .txt file and use that data in your program. To get data from a .txt file one can use the `Scanner` class as in this example:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your-txt-file.txt")));
```

Then to scan each line you should use:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    // Here you should decompose every line of string to the desired variables
}
```

You can use the `.substring()` to delete parts of a `String` and assign those values to variables.